# How to add a permission to moodle permissions?

Tags: permissions, moodle, user-permissions

When creating a new user in moodle we can select a set of permissions. 
How these permissions are created? `How I can add my new permission to this list in a systematic way?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are defined in db/access.php for each plugin/module.

http://docs.moodle.org/dev/Access_API#How_to_define_new_capabilities_in_plugins